# Discord.py Buttons (count)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I am trying to make a suggestion which uses buttons instead of reactions to vote. Everything has worked so far except two things. Here is the code:

```
        count = 0
        count +=1
        await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed2)
        print(f"{count}") #check if count has gone up
    button.callback = button_callback
```

Everytime I click on the button, instead of showing a number it shows "<class 'itertools.count'>", and everytime 'count' is 1.
[image: Screenshot of embed]

Here is the full code:

```
@client.command()
async def suggest(ctx, *, reason):
    button = Button(label="Good Suggestion", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green,)
    button2 = Button(label="Bad Suggestion", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red,)
    async def button_callback(interaction):
        count = 0
        count +=1
        print(f"{count}")
        await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed2)
    button.callback = button_callback
   
#count 2 is the same code

 async def button_callback(interaction):
        count2 = 0
        count2 +=1
        print(f"{count2}")
        await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed2)
        
    button2.callback = button_callback
    
    embed = discord.Embed(color=ctx.message.author.color, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
    embed.set_author(name=f"{ctx.message.author}({ctx.message.author.id})", icon_url= ctx.message.author.avatar)
    embed.add_field(name='Suggestion:', value=f"{reason}")
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Likes: 0 | Dislikes: 0")

    embed2 = discord.Embed(color=ctx.message.author.color, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
    embed2.set_author(name=f"{ctx.message.author}({ctx.message.author.id})", icon_url= ctx.message.author.avatar)
    embed2.add_field(name='Suggestion:', value=f"{reason}")
    embed2.set_footer(text=f"Likes: {count} | Dislikes: {count2}")
    view = View()
    view.add_item(button)
    view.add_item(button2)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed,view=view)
```

I'm not sure what to do because I have done anything I know how to do. Could someone please help me and explain what to do?

Comment: You reset the count every time you click it! Remove line 6. However because your using the functional approach rather than OOP you will need to store the value of count elsewhere. Such as a global or inside of an object.

Comment: As for the "itertools.count" inside the message, this happens because the only reference to count in this scope is "itertools.count"

Comment: That's what I tried originally. I just kept on getting the error ``local variable 'count' referenced before assignment`` But when I print count, It does go up like it should. It just won't edit the message.

Comment: So would I have to make it an integer for it to work? Because I have used similar code before and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TheLazyScripter’s approach, there’s an issue with this though, the `count` variable will get messed up as soon as the `suggest` command is invoked more than once, here’s a way to prevent that:

```py
async def suggest(ctx, *, reason):
    count = 0
    async def button_callback(interaction):
        nonlocal count
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Globally
count1 = 0
    
async def suggest(ctx, *, reason):
    async def button_callback(interaction):
            global count1  # Let the scope know that we are using count1 from the global scope
            count1 += 1
            # ... everything else
```

alternatively we could opt to pass a referance of count into the function

```
async def suggest(ctx, *, reason, count)
```

or we could opt to grab the value from the `embed` and increment. This would avoid an issue where the server stops running for whatever reason and we lose track of the current count. I guess we could also write it to a file but this would get messy with multiple buttons/embeds etc..

Comment: Yea this worked. Ty sm

Comment: Glad to have helped!